# node server http close event fires always

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a close event that fires before the server shuts down.

for this ive created the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var listenTo = require('./config/port.json')["port"];


http.listen(listenTo, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:' + listenTo);
});

http.on('close', function (event) {
    console.log('closed');
});
```

However this just shuts down the server.

So my question is how can i listen on server shut down using `http`

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692536/node-js-server-close-event-doesnt-appear-to-fire) out, I think you are using a method that closes the server instead of listening to close events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of listening for the event, you are closing the server.

Instead of this:

```
http.close(function (event) {
    console.log('closed');
});
```

you should use this:

```
http.on('close', function (event) {
    console.log('closed');
});
```

Compare this:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close

with this:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback

Note that if you want to handle events of closing the server application (terminating the process) and not just closing the `http` server (closing the open port) then you need to handle a different kind of events, like:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    console.log('SIGINT caught');
    // if you want to exit then call:
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: I have attempted this and tried CTRL + C in my console but it doesnt fire an event. am i missing something i have updated my code to what you suggested

Comment: @MarcRasmussen if you want to capture Ctrl+C then see my updated answer.