# Graceful shutdown of BullMQ workers prevents Node JS from exiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, signals, bullmq, graceful-shutdown

I follow the recommendation [here](https://docs.bullmq.io/guide/going-to-production#gracefully-shut-down-workers) and also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71170075/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-bullmq-when-running-inside-an-express-server) and I use the following code in order to gracefully shutdown `BullMQ` workers in my development environment on `Ubuntu`:

```
  const handleTermination = async () => {
    log.info(`Gracefully shutting down worker for queue '${name}'.`);
    await worker.close();
  };
  process.on('SIGTERM', handleTermination).on('SIGINT', handleTermination);
```

However the above code prevents the app from ending. The result in the console is the following for 3 consecutive `Ctrl+C`:

```
^C[2023-04-23T16:15:46.423] [INFO] development - Gracefully shutting down worker for queue 'X'.
[2023-04-23T16:15:46.423] [INFO] development - Gracefully shutting down worker for queue 'Y'.
^C[2023-04-23T16:15:47.075] [INFO] development - Gracefully shutting down worker for queue 'X'.
[2023-04-23T16:15:47.075] [INFO] development - Gracefully shutting down worker for queue 'Y'.
^C[2023-04-23T16:15:47.793] [INFO] development - Gracefully shutting down worker for queue 'X'.
[2023-04-23T16:15:47.793] [INFO] development - Gracefully shutting down worker for queue 'Y'.
```

Obviously the process is still there forever and can only be finished with `kill -9`. Note that there is no pending job.

What I am missing here?

Of course the problem is gone when I use `process.exit()` but I understand that this is not the recommended handling.

Comment: Do you also close all queues?

Comment: @rveerd what do you mean exactly? Do you mean cleaning them from any existing jobs? In most of the cases there are no jobs in the queues anyhow.

Comment: When you create a queue object with `new Queue()` BullMQ creates a connection to the Redis database. If you do not perform `queue.close()`, this connection remains active and Node.js will not exit.

Comment: @reveerd you are right. This is the correct answer. Strangely I had not found any reference on this in their documentation. Thank you.

Comment: I will post an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1):

A Node.js process will exit when there is no more work to be done. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37592669/6783775) for details.

BullMQ creates a connection to the Redis database when you create `Worker` objects. But it also creates a connection when you create `Queue` objects. To gracefully exit Node.js you have to close all connections. You have to call `close()` both on the workers **and** the queues.

Another option is to create the Redis connection yourself and pass it to the `Queue` constructor. The queue object uses the passed connection and does not create its own connection. In this case, you only have to close the Redis connection.

```js
import { Queue } from 'bullmq';
import { Redis } from 'ioredis';

const connection = new Redis();
const queue = new Queue('foo', { connection });

// create more queues with the same connection...

// post jobs to queues...

connection.quit();
```

Note that the same does not work for worker objects. A worker object creates additional connections to the Redis database. See [the documentation](https://docs.bullmq.io/guide/connections) for details.

You can easily see all active connections to the Redis database using `redis-cli`:

```
$ redis-cli CLIENT LIST
```